# why does this not vertically center?

Tags: image, html, containers, css

html code:

```
<div class="container">
  <a class="ank">
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schoolslogoNEW310113.gif" />
  </a>
</div>
```

css code:

```
.ank
{
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  line-height: 100%;
 }

 img
 {
  vertical-align: middle;
 }

 .container
 {
  display:block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 500px;
 }
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mfBZZ/5/

if i change the jsfiddle, so that anks line-height is 500px, and remove the font-size from container, it works.

but when i add the font-size to container of 500px, and then make the line-height in ank, 100% of that font-size, it doesn't work. it brings the image alittle lower than where it should be.

working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eujFY/1/

UPDATE:

this solution works for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/eujFY/2/ <---- updated.

Comment: did you try tu change the 500px of the a to 100%?

Comment: ya, you mean the anchor line-height to 100%?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen you found a solution, however it implies setting the height manually on both elements and it requires the usage of unnecessary tags.
So I suggest you to check the "display:table" (container) and "display:table-cell" (inner element) rules: http://jsfiddle.net/RxGS5/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="ank">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schoolslogoNEW310113.gif" />
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container
{
    display:table;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.ank
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```